# Possible to Search Partial Matched Strings from same table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table  and lets say the table has items with the item numbers:

```
12345
12345_DDM
345653
2345664
45567
45567_DDM
```

I am having trouble creating a query that will get all of the _DDM and the corresponding item that has the same prefix digits.

So in this case I'd want both 12345 and 12345_DDM etc to be returned

Comment: `WHERE column LIKE '%_DDM'`, you could also use `CHARINDEX(column,'_DDM') > 0`...

Comment: So you want both 12345 and 12345_DDM etc to be returned?

Comment: What sort of trouble?   What is your query and what error did you get?

Comment: @jarlh Yes sir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `like` to find rows with _DDM.

Use `EXISTS` to find rows with numbers also having a _DDM row.

<kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/KZS66193)**</kbd>

```
select *
from tablename t1
where columnname LIKE '%_DDM'
   or exists (select 1 from tablename t2
              where t1.columnname + '_DDM' = t2.columnname)
```

Comment: I dont think || is supported in SQL server

Comment: @Sentinel, it should be as it is. (For t1 12345, does a t2 12345_DDM exist?)

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I've never been good with exists and embedded selects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
--sample data
;with tbl as (
    select col from (values ('12345'),('12345_DDM'),('345653'),('2345664'), ('45567'),('45567_DDM')) A(col)
)

--select query
select col from (
    select col, 
           prefix, 
           max(case when charindex('_DDM', col) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by prefix) [prefixGroupWith_DDM]
    from (
        select col,
               case when charindex('_DDM', col) - 1 > 0 then substring(col, 1, charindex('_DDM', col) - 1) else col end [prefix]
        from tbl
    ) a
) a where [prefixGroupWith_DDM] = 1
```